# Forwarding a domain to localhost

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, forwarding

I purchased a domain name from GoDaddy. I want to make it, so that when users type the domain name in the browser URL they will see my website, but the URL not to change.

I tried Forwarding and it simply does a non-friendly redirect. Forward with masking is the ugliest thing ever, it sets up a static html page with an iframe inside.

I don't want that. The host is set up on my PC. No web hosting purchased

Answer (score 1):

You should have external ip (public). You should configure dns records in godaddy (if they provide that) and put there something like

```
> host.example.com. A yours.public.ip 
> www.host.example.com. CNAME host.example.com.
```

If not. You should set up or buy DNS service . If you would like to set up your own - try using Bind9, there is a lot of info for it.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this. There is a DNS manager and it let's me change stuff. However i have no idea what to add there. I mean i read what you wrote...but still.

Comment: Look. domain is just a name. it doesnt now where all request should go. For this purpose nameservers existst. there should be something like **park this domain** or place where some info about current nameserver is. you should look for string like "ip of . nameserver/name" or some records like yours.domain A ipaddr. Is there something like that? Look here http://help.godaddy.com/article/680?locale=en and http://help.godaddy.com/article/664#reghere

Comment: Yes there was. It says A(Host):@. And there was an IP address. I changed that IP address to mine and saved the zone file.
As for the other CNAME. There is Host:www and it points to @

Comment: Thats ok now. and you have some web server on yours PC that is configured for external interface? check it. it takes about 2-4 hours for yours ISP dns server to update their records. you can try to use google dns server 8.8.8.8 to check if yours web site is accessible. yours system is *nix or win? try nslookup domainname and dig domainname commands.